# How does Diana Allers's focus affect your War Assets?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, even though I'm playing mostly renegade, I was benevolent enough to let a reporter on board, and she's asked me what she should focus on. I told her "Cerberus is lame, report on that" but I'm curious as to how each option (recruitment or Cerberus) affects War Asset collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She'll occasionally ask for interviews.  The results of these interviews can effect other war assets.

For instance there is one after curing the genophage.  Using the Paragon dialog option drives up recruiting for the Krogan Clans asset.

There's also an instance where she's arguing with a random crew member.  You have an option of killing one of her stories if you take the crew member's side.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a difference to your war assets one way or the other. Only your actual interviews do. However, depending on your answer to her on other occasions depends on whether you get paragon or renegade points and added reputation.

Answer (score -3):

I got +10 for letting her on the Normandy.